# i am struck with the Flow of execution, can anyone help me out

Tags: c

I am confused how the expression get executed for the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[10];
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 2;
  printf("%d  %d",a[0],a[1]);
  a[0] = a[0]  - (a[0] = a[1]); // not able to understand its flow of execution
  printf("\n%d  %d",a[0],a[1]);
}
```

The output for this is

1  2

-1  2

My doubt is where the assignment operator inside that parenthesis get executed and change the a[0] element, and is used in expression, such as

index              : 0   1

element            : 1   2

during expression  : 2   2 // when (a[0] = a[1])

a[0] = a[0] - (a[0] - a[1]);

a[0] = 1 - (2);

a[0] = -1;

(or)

index              : 0   1

element            : 1   2

during expression  : 1   2 // when (a[0] = a[1])

a[0] = a[0] - (a[0] - a[1]);

a[0] = 1 - (2);

a[0] = -1;

also the associative property also confused whether expression is seen from left to right or right to left.

Comment: Even with the parenthesis? Perhaps you could explain what you think is happening.

Comment: Are you confused about everything in this program, or is it a specific line that you have issues with?

Comment: Pretty sure that it's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to change `a[0]` and use `a[0]` in the same expression.

Comment: so it get executed as like this, a[0] = 1 - (a[0] = a[1];  a[0] = 1 - 2;

Comment: You can edit the question to add more detail.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? If it was handed to you by a book or teacher, you need a new book or teacher.

Comment: Actually, if ignoring the C language completely and simply applying common sense, what is the meaning of `a[0] = a[0] - a[0];`? Start by making sense of that - if you can't, how do you expect the compiler to be able to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has *undefined behavior*.

```
a[0] = a[0]  - (a[0] = a[1]);
```

By itself, the subexpression `(a[0] = a[1])` is valid. It assigns the value of `a[1]` to `a[0]`, and yields the value that was assigned.

The problem is that `a[0]` is modified *twice* in a single expression, and the two modifications are unsequenced, meaning that the language doesn't tell us which one happens first. (In C90/C99 terms, the two modifications are not separated by a *sequence point*.)

A simpler example of this:

```
x = 2 + (x = 1);
```

Here `x` is modified twice. The language doesn't just say that the two modifications can happen in either order; it says that the behavior is undefined. In other words, the language says nothing about what will happen. It could crash, it could give you some garbage results, or, worst of all, it could do just what you expect it to do. (That's the worst case because it means you still have a serious bug that's going to be difficult to detect and diagnose it.)

Bottom line: Whatever that line of code was *intended* to do, there is certainly a clearer and less ambiguous way to do it. The code in your question, not to be too harsh, might as well not even be C.